# Microcontrollers and custom boards

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design

I am new to electrical engineering and the usage of microcontrollers. I am trying to build a custom circuit board using parts bought separately, but I'm not sure how this should be done.

Some things aren't clear to me. For example, I want my chip to control a LED that turns on and off at a specified interval. My questions are:

1. How this things should be linked? I mean the microchip has some input and output pins. The output pins should be linked to the part that controls the flow of electricity trough the LED. But what output pin, cause there are more than one.
2. If I have a USB connection connected to an input pin(or more, I'm not sure). How should I load the program in the microchip's memory? Is a boot loader needed? Do I need a special program to write the code in. I assume that I can load the code and if I want to use another code I just load the new one and overwrite the memory.
3. If I want to turn on 3 LEDs at different moments, how should the wires be linked? I guess that I can specify in the code what pin to output to but what if I want to control a lot of LEDs ?

I don't know if my questions are wrong. I'm in high school and I try to learn on myself but google can't find me everything I need.

Comment: Your questions are very basic and very broad. Each one should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Regarding USB, you can't simply connect a USB cable to some random pin since USB has specific signal voltages and waveforms. Some microcontrollers have USB-specific pins, while others (such as many Arduinos) have a separate chip onboard that acts as a bridge between USB and the microcontroller chip that you program.

Comment: "google can't find me everything I need" - google is an extremely powerful tool. But for the questions you asked, you need books, not google.

Comment: You need to understand basic electrical theory. Voltage, current, power, ohm's law and so on. Without that you won't understand anything, but once you have learned it your questions will have clear answers to you.

Comment: Rather than starting off buy building your own board, you would be better buying a ready made board that is guaranteed to work, and learning some basic electronics and software using that. Lots of people use Arduino boards, and there is a big community built up around it to give support. As an alternative you could try a STM32 Discovery board, although these are perhaps not quite well supported.

Comment: Pick a microcontroller that you would like to use.  (At your present level of understanding, it will be a fairly random pick, though.  No offense; you will get better at it with practice.)  Then read (at least skim) through every bit of literature that the manufacturer has got for the chosen microcontroller.  You might find that the microcontroller which you have chosen is not appropriate.  Find another.  Rinse an repeat.

Comment: On a slightly different note, a good book to get started is [The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics) (if you haven't read it already).  Finally, there is no royal road.

Comment: Steve's point about starting with a working board is a good one.  What is best is starting with a board for which you can get the schematic, and where it isn't too complicated.  You can do initial work there, and build up some knowledge and working code, which you can then use on your first custom board.  For all their limitations, older processor in DIP packages have the advantage that your first custom circuit can be built on a breadboard, letting you experiment more readily than a PCB where you may be stuck with certain mistakes until you make another.

Comment: Thanks! Programming isn't a problem. I'm not 100% beginner in electronics. I understand what most of the basic pieces (resistors,capacitors, etc) do, I understand both AC and DC , I know what is analog signal what is virtual signal how it is interpreted etc. You are right I should start with a prebuilt board (arduino maybe) and I would definitely read the book. Thank!

Comment: If you are confident in the electronics part of microcontrollers and want to go really into the different peripherals that they support, then I would recommend reading the datasheet for your particular chip. For instance, the complete datasheet used in Arduino's (ATMEGA328): http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1 and 3

Microcontrollers are CPUs that have special pins dedicated to electronic communication. The most basic unit is GPIO (General-purpose input/output). It allows you to program a pin as an input or an output.

As an output, you can set it to `LOW` or `HIGH` (0 or 1). A high output corresponds to a *voltage* of VCC, which is usually 5V or 3.3V. A low output corresponds to *ground* or 0V. You can think of each pin as a small battery that can be turned on or off.

As an input, you can read the voltage level. If the voltage is near VCC then the readout will be `HIGH` (1) and if it is near ground it will be `LOW` (0).

Though this sound fairly limiting, there are lots of circuits, ICs and breakout boards that communicate using this setup. In fact, this is the basis of Digital Electronics, which is a huge and exciting subject on its own.

I'm including here two basic circuits that should get you going. The first is how to connect an LED to an output GPIO pin, and the second is a pull-down push-button connected to an input GPIO pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXWcxD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You also asked about what happens if you need to drive lots of LEDs. Recall that the GPIO pins can be thought of as tiny batteries. If you have many LEDs it can become too much for the pins (to much current required). If so, you might need to use transistors as switching "helpers".

Hopefully, this should give you something to get started.

## Question 2

The USB protocol is unfortunately a little complicated. Some micro-controllers don't even support it at all. These are advanced subjects that is probably better answered in a book or some more in-depth material.

## In General

To get started, I would recommend going through the Arduino books and examples. These are great in terms of teaching and you can quickly get to a point where you can make interesting projects.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all read the data sheet and user guide of chip that you are going to use. and do some research on internet to find a schematic design for chip or most probably you should be able to find the circuit diagram on data sheet. if you gonna make your own circuit board for micro controller, you have to do a PCB design. to load the program to the chip you have to buy a programmer or you can build a programmer too. But its better to buy a programmer, since you are new to micro-controller programming.